# Control my Casio Xcilim EX-Z35 from my Windows XP computer

Tags: windows-xp, camera

At work we need to take pictures for id badges with an Casio Xcilim EX-Z35.

Instead of having to hold the camera and take the pictures, plug it in and move the file, I was wondering if I would be able to use said camera through my computer (running Windows XP computer) as it hangs on a wall/ceiling mount.

That way I could simply click “take picture” and have it automatically placed in the folder specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Mac, [Image Capture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_Capture) can do this.

[image]

<sub>[Image credit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Imagecapture.png)</sub>

Comment: forgot to mention I'm on XP.